# Trying to add Neo4j into eclipse

Tags: java, maven, neo4j, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to add Neo4j dependencies into a maven project that I have created in Eclipse Kepler. I am following the steps mentioned at the link:

[StepsToIntegrateNeo4j](https://neo4j.com/blog/how-to-set-up-a-maven-project-with-neo4j-in-eclipse/)

However, I am not getting the Neo4j pulgin from the repository. I am stuck at the following step:

[image]

What should I do for this?

Comment: Eclipse artifact search is not reliable. The indices are either not downloaded or way to old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why the search is not working but here what's you can do.

1) On your `pom.xml` add below code :

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>your version</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

or

2) On that dialog just fill the `Group Id, Artifact Id and Version` and click `ok` and then save your `pom.xml`.

Maven will download the dependencies.

***EDIT:***

It seems that you can find the dependency on that search box only when that dependency is present on your local repo. So, for the first time you have to take one of the above approaches.